# How do I trim multiple mysql tables by date via a script executed by cron or by an ssh tty command line?

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

I am trying to figure out how to write a bash script similar to the one found @ https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20240/running-sql-query-on-all-databases that I can execute via cron. I, personally, intend to execute this script on mysql servers running on CentOS 6.8 and Ubuntu 14.4 and above.

I have a database "DB123" with two tables "tbl001" and "tbl002". (The DB and table names are generic fabrications.)

In tbl001, there is a column "tbl001date" (type datetime") with cell values like "2015-10-26 16:14:45".

In tbl002, there is a column "tbl002time" (type datetime") with cell values like "2015-10-26 16:14:45".

I figured out how to query manually via phpMyAdmin to delete all rows older than "a given time":

```
DELETE FROM `tbl001` WHERE `tbl001date` <= '2016-09-01 00:00:00'
DELETE FROM `tbl002` WHERE `tbl002time` <= '2016-11-01 00:00:00'
```

What I am looking to do is have the script delete rows older than 90 days in tbl001, delete rows older than 30 days in tbl002, and so on... Like the script referred to above, I think declaring variables would be a smart choice.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# mysql credential 
user="root"
pass="root" 

# database name
database="DB123"

# list tables, columns, days to keep A thru Z
tableA="tbl001"
columnA="tbl001date"
daysA="90"
tableB="tbl002"
columnB="tbl002time"
daysB="30"
#And so on....

#Script Section 1:  Scripting to display a formatted table of worh about to be done the executes when script is ran from TTY command line but NOT when ran via cron...
#Example of what I envision for screen output when ran TTY command line...

If connection to mysql fails, notify user and quit. ie "Sorry, was unable to connect mysql server."  OR

If mysql credentials are invalid, notify user and quit. ie "The user/password combo declared are invalid, please verify your credentials and try again." OR

If a defined table or column does not exist, notify the user and quit. ie "$tableC, $tableD, and $tablesE do(es) not exist in $database, please verify the variables declared in this script." OR

The following tables will have rows older than "DATE" deleted...
TABLE          |DATE    
------------------------------------
echo "$tableA"  | (90 days before Today's Date)
echo "$tableB"  | (30 days before Today's Date)
echo "$tableC"  | (X days before Today's Date)
And so on...
Then output the following and wait for a response from user:

Is the above correct? (Type YES to continue/any this else to quit)

#Script Section 2:  Additional scripting to delete rows goes here...

#Script Section 3:  Additional scripting to compact the database after deleting rows to remove "overhead"

#Script Section 4:  Additional scripting to output results without regard to cron or tty execution

The mysql database, $database, on server $dnsdomainname had the following table rows deleted:
$tablaA had $number-of-rows deleted and was reduced/compacted from 200MB to 35MB in size
$tableB had $number-of-rows deleted and was reduced/compacted from 500MB to 75MB in size
And so on...
```

I'm not committed to using BASH script. If it makes more sense to use Perl, or another language I'm completely open to the idea.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: did you ask a question? don't see one though

Comment: I need help/direction on writing a script that will accomplish the above.

Comment: To delete rows with a date older than x days, you can use `delete from $tableA where $columnA <= date_add(now(), interval - $daysA day);` and execute that exactly like in your linked question, in any other script language or even as an event completely in mysql. You can just hardcode it and execute it in a cronjob once a day. Or do it as complicated/userfriendly/customizable as you want. You can share your final script by posting it as an answer for other users with the same problem.